Finding Volume of Revolution Given by $y = \sin x$
The question given is to find the volume of revolution generated by the graph of $y = \sin x$ on the interval $[0, \pi]$.
The way I attempted was to form the sums of cylindrical segments given by $\sum_0^{\pi} \pi (\sin x)^2 \Delta x$, and as $\Delta x$ approaches zero, this sum approaches the definite integral $\int_0^{\pi} \pi \sin^2 x dx$. To evaluate the integral, I proceeded as follows:
$$\int_0^{\pi} \pi \sin^2 x \ dx = \pi \int_0^{\pi} \frac{1– \cos 2x}{2} \ dx = \frac{\pi}{2} \left[x \ – \frac{\sin 2x}{2}\right]_0^{\pi} = \frac{\pi^2}{2}$$
Is this correct? Thank you in advance.

This all seems fine apart from the $\frac{\pi^3}{3}$ at the end. Should it not be $\frac{\pi^2}{2}$?

@ljfirth ahh yes! Thank you for noticing that!

Volume of revolution generated about what axis of rotation?  From your computation, it would seem to be the volume generated by rotating $y = \sin x$ about the $x$-axis, but you should specify this in your problem statement.

@heropup I see! I'll be sure to specify it in the future. Thank you for noticing!
